# Multiple Errors In Code

Tags: c++

Theese are the errors

I asked on the website where I am doing the course at my the answer I was given I either do not understand, it is not clear enough or it it complete shit, I have been looking for 2 days for solutions for this  and with all the edits I have done it has not worked]

anyway here is  the answer I was given
"In the header you are trying to define functions multiple times. as you can see here on lines 6&15, and  7&18" I have changed the int's around and it still does not work so could somebody possibly explain in more detail or just give me the correct code please:

My Code is

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "FBullCowGame.h"
void PrintIntro();
std::string GetGuess();
void PlayGame();
bool AskToPlayAgain();
FBullCowGame BCGame; // instantiate a new game

// the entry point for our application
int main() { 
 bool bPlayAgain = false;
 do {
 PrintIntro();
 PlayGame();
 // TODO add game summary
 bPlayAgain = AskToPlayAgain();
 } while (bPlayAgain);
 return 0;
}
// introduce the game
void PrintIntro() {
 constexpr int WORD_LENGTH = 5;
 std::cout << "Welme To Bulls and Cows, a fun word game.\n";
 std::cout << "Can you guess the " << WORD_LENGTH << " letter isogram I'm thinking of? \n ";
}
//Play the game
void PlayGame() {
 BCGame.Reset;
 int MaxTries = BCGame.GetMaxTries(); // checks how many tries the game has got
 std::cout << "MaxTries = " << MaxTries << "\n";
 // loop for the number of turns asking for our guesses 
 // TODO make while looop
 for (int count = 1; count <= MaxTries; count++) {
 std::string Guess = GetGuess(); // TODO check valid guesses
 std::cout << "Your guess was " << Guess << "\n";
 }
 return;
}
// get a guess from the player
std::string GetGuess() {
 int CurrentTry = BCGame.GetCurrentTry();
 std::cout << "Try " << CurrentTry << ". Enter your guess: ";
 std::string Guess = "";
 std::getline(std::cin, Guess);
 return Guess;
}
bool AskToPlayAgain() {
 std::cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n) \n ";
 std::string Response = "";
 std::getline(std::cin, Response);
 return (Response[0] == 'y') || (Response[0] == 'Y');
}
```

Header

```
#pragma once
#include<string>
// senpai notice me
class FBullCowGame { 
public:
 FBullCowGame(); // contructor
 bool Reset(); // make a more rich return valuve
 int GetMaxTries()const;
 int GetCurrentTry()const;
 bool IsGameWon()const;
 bool CheckGuessCorrect(std::string); // make a rich return value
 // TODO make a method  to get bulls and cowws
//Focus above ,not here
private:
 int MyCurrentTry ; // find the contructor or somthing
 int MyMaxTries;
};
```

Fbullcowgame,.cpp

```
#include "FBullCowGame.h"
FBullCowGame::FBullCowGame() {
 Reset();
}
int FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries() const { return MyMaxTries;}
int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry() const { return MyCurrentTry;}
bool FBullCowGame::Reset() {

 constexpr int MyMaxTries = 8;
 MyCurrentTry = 1;
 return MyMaxTries;
}

int FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries() const {
 return;
}
int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry() const {
 return MyCurrentTry;
}
bool FBullCowGame::IsGameWon() const {
 return false;
}
bool FBullCowGame::CheckGuessCorrect(std::string) {
 return false;
}
```

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State

```
Error C2084 function 'int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry(void) const' already has a body BullCowGame 
c:\users\nem\documents\unrealcorse\section_2\section_02\bullcowgame\fbullcowgame.cpp 22 
Error C2084 function 'int FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries(void) const' already has a body BullCowGame 
c:\users\nem\documents\unrealcorse\section_2\section_02\bullcowgame\fbullcowgame.cpp 18 
Error C3867 'FBullCowGame::Reset': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member BullCowGame c:\users\nem\documents\unrealcorse\section_2\section_02\bullcowgame\main.cpp 33
```

Comment: It's better to copy the errors from the Output tab of Visual Studio.

Comment: "it is not clear enough or it it complete shit". Your question itself suffers from some of these problems. Using appropriate punctuation and capitalization, leaving out the complaints at the beginning, improving the punctuation on your code, and stripping out those functions that aren't problematic to create a Minimum Working Example would improve it.

Comment: The Output Tab is in a better format than the Error List for copying and pasting errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> function 'int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry(void) const' already has a body BullCowGame

The function `int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry(void)` is defined twice (meaning the second time it is seen, it already has a body).

```
1. int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry() const { return MyCurrentTry;}

2. int FBullCowGame::GetCurrentTry() const {
        return MyCurrentTry;
   }
```

> C2084 function 'int FBullCowGame::GetMaxTries(void) const' already has a body BullCowGame

Same goes for the second error.

> C3867 'FBullCowGame::Reset': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

You missed the `()` when trying to call this method. This assumes that you're trying to reference the function itself, hence the error relating to pointer to member.

```
BCGame.Reset;
```

Comment: Sorry for replying so late however I did fix it and you were a lot of help and from this post I have understood more so how to ask questions properly